# Converting VB Script into Python

Tags: python, arcmap, convert, vb

I have some old VB scripts which an I am wanting to turn them into Python.

My old VB code reads

```
If [LAND_TYPE]="RESVE" Then val = [LAND_NAME]
elseIf [LAND_NAME] = "UCL" Then val = [LAND_NAME] 
elseIf [LOTNO] <> "" then val = "Lot " & [LOTNO]
else
end if
```

```
LotNo_F = Val
```

[image]

I have attempted to turn this into a Python code, i have used update cursor

```
fc = CAD
fields = ["LAND_TYPE", "LAND_NAME", "LOTNO", "LotNo_F" ]

# Create update cursor for feature class
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

        if row[0] == "RESVE":
            row[3] = row[1]
        elif row[1] == "UCL":
            row[3] = row[1]
        elif row[2] != "":
            row[3] = "Lot" + row[1]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

It all works fine except for my last `elif` statement, it runs but it does not produce the same output as the VB script.

I am a little stumped to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You can use field calculator with a python expression, that would probably make it more familiar though I suggest don't use the horrid interface that pops up, indent is very important for python and that box/font combo is hard to follow (was that 2 spaces or 3??) Use a good editor like Notepad++ or PyWin32 (even IDLE if you must) with a fixed width font to help line up the indents then copy/paste into the field calculator to perform the operation. Have a read of https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002m000000 as a primer to get started with python field calcs.

Comment: Indentation matters in python. Your `cursor.updateRow(row)` line is only run when the `elif` is true.